# combine tap and doubletap ionic events

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I'm searched a few examples but I don't found anything that solved my problem.
My problem is very simple, I need a one element with two events, one tap and double tap event.
I do this but the events bind together and I don't need this.. 
I need that I tap on element two times (doubletap), the state of element is selected, and if I tap one time the element is deselected and now is not selected.
I do this too and the result is the same, events fired together...
Anybody know how do this??

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve it with

```
         $scope.onDoubleTap = function(event){
                setTimeout(function(){

                    if(!$(element).hasClass("selected")) {
                        $(element).addClass("selected");

                    ......
                    }
                },400);
            };
        $scope.onTap = function(event){

                if($(element).hasClass("selected")){
                     $(element).removeClass("selected");

                    .....
                }


        };
```

Comment: I am assuming here that you wrote these methods inside a controller. Isn't  DOM manipulation inside the controller a bad practice? Also, when its angular, why are'nt you using $timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

See the Pen [Tap and Double Tap Ionic](http://codepen.io/Vikasg7/pen/GWybgK/) by Vikas Gautam ([@Vikasg7](http://codepen.io/Vikasg7)) on [CodePen](http://codepen.io).

Here is the Directive :-

```
  SepTap.$inject = ["$ionicGesture"]
  function SepTap(IonicGesture) {
      return {
         restrict: "A",
         link: linkFunc
      }

      function linkFunc(scope, ele, attrs) {
         var isDoubleTap = false

         var tap = IonicGesture.on("tap", onTap, ele)
         var doubleTap = IonicGesture.on("doubletap", onDoubleTap, ele)

         function onTap() {
            setTimeout(onTap, 250)
            function onTap() {
               if (isDoubleTap) return
               scope.$apply(attrs.stTap)
            }
         }

         function onDoubleTap() {
            isDoubleTap = true
            scope.$apply(attrs.stDoubleTap)
            // onTap is called twice almost immediadetly with a delay
            // of 250ms, so using a delay of 300ms (50ms more) to 
            // reset isDoubleTap to false.
            setTimeout(function () { isDoubleTap = false }, 300)
         }

         ele.on("$destroy", function () {
            IonicGesture.off(tap, "tap", onTap)
            IonicGesture.off(doubleTap, "doubletap", onDoubleTap)
         })
      }    
   }
```

Please check the above codepen for full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-series-13-touch-gestures/ says in comments section that ionic has disabled onTap related delay, which is used for detecting these tap types separately. No workaround was mentioned, only that it is not possible to distinguih them out of the box.

Snippet text:

> Unfortunately, changes done one year ago removed 300ms click delay from Ionic applications. I'm saying its unfortunately because now application can't correctly detect tap/double-tap on the same element. Both of them will trigger.

Comment: if ionic has disabled related delay, can I resolve this with a one setTimeout() ??

Comment: I solve it with setTimeout in DoubleTap event. Thanks